# Show a 10k user all questions they have interacted with even if they were deleted

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, deleted-questions

I would like the ability to view, as normal, in my profile page, all questions that I have interacted with, whether they were subsequently deleted or not. This is related to  [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) , but not the same.

I've recently reached 10k and can finally see deleted posts ([the proposal one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424226/this-is-weird-but-serious-this-is-not-a-joke) was a little disappointing). However, as has been noted before, it's fairly difficult to find deleted posts. I understand the reasoning behind this and I have no desire to go round trying to track down most of the crap that gets deleted to get some vicarious thrills around a differently coloured background; even if it was originally posted by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3318433/458741) (pure luck I swear; it was the first question in the low quality posts queue).

However, if *I* have interacted with a post it is because I had an interest in it. Maybe I upvoted; maybe I commented and asked the OP to clarify with the intention of going back. Either way I had the ability to find the post easily enough.

By deleting it you remove that option and my ability to find the post to try to better it or vote to undelete.

It's not like I have a lot of (un)delete votes and can go around undeleting a lot of stuff and there are mechanisms in place so that other users can catch me at it and stop me.

They could be rendered as [Class OOP correct [deleted]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138396/class-oop-correct) instead of [Class OOP correct [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138396/class-oop-correct) (this is not a good candidate for undeletion just an example).

If this goes too far then it'd work almost as well if it was show me deleted questions I upvoted or commented on.

---

Immediate downvote... just to clarify again. I'm not looking to have easy access to all deleted content. I'd like to be able to find content that I was interested in more easily. Almost by definition, this excludes questions or answers that I have flagged or reviewed.

Comment: If you find a post worthy of future attention, just favorite it. You can see deleted questions in the favorites tab.

Comment: Bumped by community; there's a first time for everything... I know @sha, you don't know what's going to get deleted though do you :-). If I comment on a question and the OP doesn't answer immediately I expect to be able to find the question again. If it gets deleted in the meantime I can't find the question again. If I favourited most questions I commented on then I'll just have a ridiculously long list.